# How to make Linux system recognizes /dev/sda1 as /dev/sdb1

Tags: udev, d-bus

I am not asking about mounting.

I boot Linux OS from a USB flash drive (`/dev/sda`) in a PC that doesn't have other disks.

The `/dev/sda` includes linux OS and many partitions.

`/dev/sda1`: storage partition (fat32)

`/dev/sda3`: Linux OS partition (ext2)

The problem what I face is the Linux OS thinks the `/dev/sda1` is on a boot device.

I want to revise some system conf files or use tricky ways, to make `/dev/sda1` as a pehripheral disk like an ordinary USB storage.

Then it will be appear on File Manager App automatically (I don't want to modify File Manager App).

So tried to make a symlink `/dev/sdb1` for `/dev/sda1` with `/lib/udev/rules.d/`.

But didn't work since `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sda1` both refer same path `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda8`

Please suggest creative ideas.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. Essentially, you should change all configuration that relies on /dev/sda1 to either use /dev/sdb1, or better: configure it to use UUID (at least that's how you do it for /etc/fstab and the kernel command line, which is probably the only place that cares).